# Resize not applied blender 2.8

Tags: animation

I'm trying to resize a model with animation, but when I start the animation the model resizes to its original size and the change in size is not applied. How can I apply the changed size and stop my model from reverting to its original size? I'm using Blender 2.8 and my model is imported from an FBX file.

[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Could it be that you have keyframed the size as well?

Comment: @RobertGützkow i update the ask with image you can understand now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that the scale of the object is keyframed (animated), thus the change in scale is resetting to the value assigned in the animation. In order to change it, you can remove the keyframes on its scale by:

1. Selecting the object you want to scale
2. Opening the *Object Properties*
3. Right-clicking the *Scale* properties
4. Selecting *Clear Keyframes* in order to delete all keyframes for the scale

Afterwards you should be able to resize the object.

[image: Clear keyframes]

Comment: Thanks is this <3